# WITH queries with INSERT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to do something that I'm almost positive works in Postgresql:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT something FROM something WHERE something.name='reference')
INSERT INTO somewhere (id, name)
SELECT cte.id, 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.id, 'Frank'
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.id, 'Thomas'
;
```

In other words, I want to grab the "something" row to be used for a bunch of new rows in "somwhere". Each new entry should have a reference (like  foreign key value) back to the same "something" row in the cte, mostly just to avoid a mess. However, MySQL is giving me that "blank stare" syntax error mechanism. Does MySQL allow `WITH ... INSERT ...;`?

Here's the actual code; it's just setting up test data:

```
WITH
  pr AS (SELECT pr_id from property AS p WHERE p.pr_name = 'Royal Oaks Plaza'),
  u AS (SELECT pr.pr_id AS pr_id, utyp.utyp_name AS utyp_name, utyp.utyp_id AS utyp_id FROM unit_type AS utyp, pr)
    INSERT INTO unit (pr_id, unt_number, utyp_id, unt_size)
    SELECT pr_id, '100', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000)
      FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'BEAUTY'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pr_id, '110', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000)
      FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'RESTAURANT'
;
```

Comment: I wouldn't know why it wouldn't work, a CTE is just syntactic sugar. What is the actual error?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I know the question is strictly about MySQL, but I thought it would be of secondary interest if a Postgresql person could tell my I'm crazy.

Comment: @HoneyBadger it the the standard (*robot voice*) "Something is wrong" message. One problem with the MySQL errors is that it seems to be quite inaccurate in reporting the exact spot where the error was encountered, and even the correct *line*.

Comment: No clue as to whcich line gives the error?

Comment: Well I have *clues* but it's often wrong by a few lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL the `INSERT` goes before the `CTE` definition, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO somewhere (id, name)
WITH cte AS (SELECT id FROM something WHERE something.name='reference')
SELECT cte.id, 'John' FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.id, 'Frank' FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.id, 'Thomas' FROM cte;
```

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wzXpDaLDJn6bF2tfnCT6yq/0)**

So I think the following would work:

```
INSERT INTO unit (pr_id, unt_number, utyp_id, unt_size)
WITH
  pr AS (SELECT pr_id from property AS p WHERE p.pr_name = 'Royal Oaks Plaza'),
  u AS (SELECT pr.pr_id AS pr_id, utyp.utyp_name AS utyp_name, utyp.utyp_id AS utyp_id FROM unit_type AS utyp, pr)
    SELECT pr_id, '100', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000)
      FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'BEAUTY'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pr_id, '110', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000)
      FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'RESTAURANT'
;
```

Comment: Ah! I could find that nowhere in the documentation explicitly, but I guess it makes syntactic sense. Well a little more. Thanks.

Comment: This is also valid ANSI/ISO SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a subquery to do the `UNION ALL` because `CTE` only can be used in the first query.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT something FROM something WHERE something.name='reference')
INSERT INTO somewhere (id, name)
SELECT id,name
FROM (
    SELECT cte.id, 'John' name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.id, 'Frank'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.id, 'Thomas'
) t1;
```

so you can do that in your query

```
WITH
  pr AS (SELECT pr_id from property AS p WHERE p.pr_name = 'Royal Oaks Plaza'),
  u AS (SELECT pr.pr_id AS pr_id, utyp.utyp_name AS utyp_name, utyp.utyp_id AS utyp_id FROM unit_type AS utyp, pr)
    INSERT INTO unit (pr_id, unt_number, utyp_id, unt_size)
    SELECT pr_id,utyp_id,num
    FROM (
        SELECT pr_id, '100', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000)
        FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'BEAUTY'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pr_id, '110', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000) num
        FROM u WHERE utyp_name = 'RESTAURANT'
    ) t1
;
```

from your query I would rewrite by `IN` instead of `UNION ALL`

```
WITH
  pr AS (SELECT pr_id from property AS p WHERE p.pr_name = 'Royal Oaks Plaza'),
  u AS (SELECT pr.pr_id AS pr_id, utyp.utyp_name AS utyp_name, utyp.utyp_id AS utyp_id FROM unit_type AS utyp, pr)
    INSERT INTO unit (pr_id, unt_number, utyp_id, unt_size)
    SELECT pr_id, '110', utyp_id, FLOOR(500 + RAND() * 2000) num
    FROM u 
    WHERE utyp_name IN ('RESTAURANT','BEAUTY')
    
;
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this

Comment: I would like to do the `IN` but each row has a unique other field (a "unit number").

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept script for mySQL "INSERT WITH"

```
CREATE TABLE fromm field char(10));
INSERT INTO fromm VALUES ('Hello!');
CREATE TABLE too field char(10));
INSERT INTO too (field) 
WITH pre AS 
( SELECT field f FROM fromm)
SELECT f FROM pre;
SELECT field FROM too;
DROP TABLE fromm;
DROP TABLE too;
```